# My function loads many times after show.bs.modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I am trying to use toastr to show an account alert if the modal opens

The problem is when I open the modal;
The alert is shown only once when I click on the button to open the modal (As it should be, this is perfect), but the second time I open the modal the alert is shown 2 times
The third time I open the modal the alert is shown 5 times
and so on, 9, 12, 18, 24, 32 times.
It is as if they are multiplying so I put a: `console.log("Modal Open")` and that's what comes out on the console:

[Output Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RDNbP.png)

This is my code, I appreciate the help, since I don't know why that is happening

```js
function edit_order(tbody, datatable) {
//ON CLICK <a class="edit"></a>
        $(tbody).on("click", "a.edit", function() {
           
        $('#myModal2').on('show.bs.modal', function(event) {
              
          var modal = $(this);
          console.log("Modal Open");
              
        })
   });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because you use an event handler to settle another.

Every times `edit_order` runs, an event handler is registered to listen to click events. And when that occurs, a new `show.bs.modal` event handler is registered. So if you run the `edit_order` more than once, you have multiple handlers to set some new hadlers for `#myModal2`... And here is the multiplication effect.

So given that very tiny code, I would suggest a quick fix: use [`.one()`](https://api.jquery.com/one/) instead of [`on()`](https://api.jquery.com/on/) for the click on `a.edit`. So the handler on `#myModal2` would be setted only once.

**But** it would be a nice idea to review how you set you event handlers... You probably do the same mistake many places. **Reminder: Do not use an event to register an event handler.** ;)

So here is the quick fix that should work for that one:

```
function edit_order(tbody, datatable) {
//ON CLICK <a class="edit"></a>
  $(tbody).one("click", "a.edit", function() {  // <-- .one here

    $('#myModal2').on('show.bs.modal', function(event) {

      var modal = $(this);
      console.log("Modal Open");

    })
  });
}
```

In short, that should be enough (Why is that in a named-function anyway?):

```
$('#myModal2').on('show.bs.modal', function(event) {

  var modal = $(this);
  console.log("Modal Open");
})
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reply.